# Setting maximum time allowed for a group policy to be allowed and then setting back to default

Tags: group-policy

We have to make accounts for certain users who work on location and their passwords are 3 characters. We disable password complexity and minimum length when we make these accounts and then renable it when we are done.

Is there anyway I can make a script to only allow this change for ~10 minutes before reverting back to requiring the original length and password complexity?

Comment: Boy is that ugly.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows/Active Directory are you on?  If you're on 2008 native mode, you can actually now have multiple password policies within a domain.  That would be much cleaner than the hack you're currently using.

Comment: Well the thing is I am not technically the network admin. I don't have that control and from what I understand he doesn't want to enforce multiple policies (don't ask me why). That is why I wanted to automate it so we could stay somewhat secure without making any changes.

Comment: Then he needs to find a new job.

Comment: So can you answer my original question?

Comment: You don't want an answer to your original question. You think you do, but down that way lies heartache and pain.

Comment: @sahh: Ypu need to find out why your network admin is not supporting your business requirements.